# requests.exceptions.ProxyError: (MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingfa ce.co', port=443)

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, huggingface

I am facing below issue while loading the pretrained BERT model from HuggingFace due to SSL certificate error.

```
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: (MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingfa
ce.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/models/hkunlp/instructor-xl 
(Caused by ProxyError('Unable to connect to proxy', SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF oc
curred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1129)'))))"), '(Request ID: 1dddbdbe-8f1d-45b7-9a43-3eed243a06be)')
```

Anyone CAN help me get through it.